# If I have an issue with expatriates

Tags: discussion

On the [tour page](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/tour) I noticed it says this about questions to ask on the site:

> Ask about...
>
> - Specific issues with expatriates

So if a user has an issue with expatriates this seems to be the site to ask about it? I suspect this is an accidental wording which says something other than what it was intended to say. I assume this site is primarily for expatriates and not so much for people who have issues with expatriates.

Perhaps one of these other wordings would be better:

> - Specific issues experienced as an expatriate
> - Specific issues with living as an expatriate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well spotted. I assume it comes from the template, so for example on the travel site it'd say "specific issues with travel", and it's just been copied.

I've updated the text. Thanks!